# How to remove an array of object and change the the structure of the object in the JavaScript or TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I am looking for solutions to change the structure of an object which have multiple array of objects to access the object directly.

**console.log(value.data.summary[0].data)**

As I donot want access arrays with this way so I want to change the structure of my data, Is there any way I can achieve something like result object ?

This way I can access nested array of object directly?

I would like to achieve something like in result object.

```js
  let value =   {
   "data":{
      "summary":[
         {
            "code":"9280",
            "data":[
               {
                  "val1":"test1",
                  "val2":"CAD",
                  "val3":0,
               },
               {
                  "val1":"test2",
                  "val2":"USD",
                  "val3":0,
               },
            ]
         },
      ]
   }
}

  let result =   {
   "data": {
      "code":"9280",
      "summary":[
               {
                  "val1":"test1",
                  "val2":"CAD",
                  "val3":0,
               },
               {
                  "val1":"test2",
                  "val2":"USD",
                  "val3":0,
               },
            
         
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: It is very unclear what you're willing to achieve. An expected result as well as the code you wrote attempting to solve it would help.

Comment: @LaurentS. I thought the same but there's a `let result` block below.

Comment: @app have you looked over Array.prototype methods like `.map()`, `.reduce()` or tried a for loop yet?

Comment: Updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to change the *value* to be the *result* you can do it in this way

```js
  let value =   {
   "data":{
      "summary":[
         {
            "code":"9280",
            "data":[
               {
                  "val1":"test1",
                  "val2":"CAD",
                  "val3":0,
               },
               {
                  "val1":"test2",
                  "val2":"USD",
                  "val3":0,
               },
            ]
         },
      ]
   }
}
let result =  {data:{
  code:value.data.summary[0].code,
  summary:[...value.data.summary[0].data]}};
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give the objects in the data array a key:

```
let value = {
  "data":{
    "summary":[
      {
        "code":"9280",
        "data":{
          0: {
              "val1":"test1",
              "val2":"CAD",
              "val3":0,
            },
          "sum2": {
            "val1":"test2",
            "val2":"USD",
            "val3":0,
          },
        }
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

You could do the same for the summary array, but I don't know if that's what you looking for. Alternatively, make summary array into one single object.

```
// Summary with keys
let value = {
  "data":{
    "summary": {
      "sum1": {
        "code":"9280",
        "data":{
          0: {
              "val1":"test1",
              "val2":"CAD",
              "val3":0,
            },
          1: {
            "val1":"test2",
            "val2":"USD",
            "val3":0,
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// Summary as a single object
let value = {
  "data":{
    "summary": {
      "code":"9280",
      "data":{
        0: {
            "val1":"test1",
            "val2":"CAD",
            "val3":0,
          },
        "example": {
          "val1":"test2",
          "val2":"USD",
          "val3":0,
        }
    }
  }
}
```